Combinatorial game of characteristic 3
Question
I'm looking for a 2-player combinatorial game $x = \{X_L \mid X_R\}$ such that $$x+x+x \equiv 0 \not\equiv x.$$
Motivation
The reason I'm asking is because these combinatorial games have a subset which forms a field of characteristic 0 (the Surreal numbers) and of characteristic 2 (the Nimbers).
When I say '$x$ of characteristic $k$' I mean you can only get 0 from adding $x $ a multiple of $k$ times to itself. This will be denoted by $\operatorname{char}(x)=k$.
It may surprise you that you can also find combinatorial games of characteristic a power of 2:
$$
\begin{array}{r|ccccc}
\operatorname{char}(x_n) & 2 & 2^2 & 2^3 & \dots & 2^{n+1} \\ \hline
x_n & * & \{1+* \mid -1\} & \{2+\{1+* \mid -1\} \mid -2\} & \dots & x_{n+1} = \{n+x_n \mid -n\}
\end{array}
$$
Now things get interesting. I tried to look for games of characteristic 3 that were born at day 3 or earlier using my computer.
I found none.
Either this means there may be games of characteristic 3 born from day 4 and on, or that there are none at all! These limited examples look as if they were saying that it isn't possible, but that's far from any evidence.
Maybe there are none because I'm looking at 2-player combinatorial games, and thus will only get games of characteristic 0 or a power of 2. Who's to say.

(The key to searching here is that the standard term for what  you're calling "characteristic" is: "order" in the context of group/monoid theory.)

I know, but combinatorial games feel like more than just a group with multiplication sometimes being defined...

Under normal play, they're a partially-ordered group. However, most games aren't (surreal) numbers, so they're arguably not any more than that.

What about games with an infinite birthday?

If you allow infinite birthdays/transfinite games,   then yes, examples with $G+G+G=0$ do exist.

Do you happen to have an example? Or is there one in Aaron N. Siegel's book?

That would probably be a good question to ask separately on Math.SE, but yes, Siegel gives an example towards the end of VIII.1.
